# Free online XML editor

Tags: gratis, web-apps, text-editor, xml, hosted

I was suprised to find no free **online** XML editors that had an easy to use visual interface (like Xml Spy but online). With grid or treeview editing of nodes and a user friendly way to edit XML.

XML easily lends itself to an online presentation and it's been around for decades now.

Any suggestions of a product that's at the intersection of free, online and quality?

Not a duplicate: Windows / Mac editors are not what I'm looking for. They are not online but run locally, which is quite different. **I don't want to install anything.**

Comment: Any specific features you'd find essential or nice-to-have? And a definition of "suck", as to avoid such? ;) Might ring a bell with someone – and improve your question ;)

Answer (score 2):

Apart from publishing the app via a Terminal Server, I could suggest [Code Beauty](http://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer).

I don't really know any of your requirements, or what you need the tool to perform, but believe this tool meets your requirements:

- Online, do not need to install anything
- Free
- "Tree View"
- "Beautify" - I am not exactly sure what this *actually* does
- Load URL / Download / Export to CSV
- XML to JSON

The only other option I have been able to locate (and keep in mind, I do not use these applications) would be [TurtleBite](http://xml-editor.kaegi.net/app/en)- you will need to make an account for this tool.

Comment: Sorry but Code Beautify is not a visual editor and TurtleBite is not user friendly. It's very difficult do get anything done in it. Try it and you'll see what I mean. +1 for trying.

Comment: That's all good, it wasn't a valid answer (: I don't "XML" much haha, and never on the web so sorry, I just tried to locate an option for you. Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this tool [Online XML Editor](http://codedestine.com/xml-editor.html) It has many features like :-

- Tree view
- minify and pretty print your xml
- save you xml online and share it with your colleagues
- Create new Element node or text node (pcdata and cdata node) by using add button on tree view bar
- delete node
- copy and paste node and its all children
- add and edit attributes and many more

Comment: not bad. E and T are reversed on the toolbar. No ability to edit directly in the treeview. Hopefully it will come along in time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For online apps that understand XML Schema and provide a graphical interface for editing, there's currently three options:

- [Daxe](https://adopt.github.io/daxe/demo/daxe.html?config=config/XMLSchema_config.xml&file=config/XHTML5.xsd)
- [Doctored.js](https://holloway.github.io/doctored/) (Double-click text to create a new element.)
- [jQuery.xmleditor](https://unc-libraries.github.io/jquery.xmleditor/demo/mods.html)

[Xonomy](http://www.lexiconista.com/xonomy/) is a notable mention for having a graphical interface with autocomplete and drop-down attribute selection, but it uses a custom schema format, not XML Schema or DTD.

Here's an exhaustive list of online XML editors which don't understand or enforce XML Schema, with some quick notes on their pros and cons:

- [Ace](https://ace.c9.io/build/kitchen-sink.html) - A general-purpose source code editor. No XML-specific features.
- **[CodeBeautify.org](https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer) - Most features of this list, eg. export to JSON or CSV, beautify or minify, [pastebin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastebin) storage and sharing.**
- [CodeDestine XML Editor](http://codedestine.com/xml-editor.html) - Inadequate
- [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/) - A general-purpose source code editor
- **[Online Xml Tools XML Editor](https://onlinexmltools.com/edit-xml) - Best for dealing with potential errors. Can pass code as a URL parameter.**
- [TutorialsPoint Online XML Editor](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_xml_editor.htm) - Inadequate
- **[XmlGrid.net](http://xmlgrid.net/) - Has element reference help**
- [XML Webpad](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=xmlwebpad) - No active site, but code still available
- **[XML:Wrench](http://xmlwrench.com/online/) - XPath and XSLT**

You can see a comparison of their unimpressive features on Wikipedia at [Comparison of XML editors#Web applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_XML_editors#Web_applications).